# Convert a column of data type Int64 with <NA> values to object with nan values

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

A tutorial had this dataframe `sequels` as follows:

```
              title sequel
id                        
19995        Avatar    nan
862       Toy Story    863
863     Toy Story 2  10193
597         Titanic    nan
24428  The Avengers    nan

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4803 entries, 19995 to 185567
Data columns (total 2 columns):
title     4803 non-null object
sequel    4803 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 272.6+ KB
```

The tutorial provided a file `sequels.p`. However, when I read the file in, my dataframe was different to that of the tutorial

```
my_sequels = pd.read_pickle('data/pandas/sequels.p')
my_sequels.set_index('id', inplace=True)
my_sequels.head()
             title  sequel
id      
19995       Avatar  <NA>
862      Toy Story  863
863    Toy Story 2  10193
597        Titanic  <NA>
24428  The Avengers <NA>

sequels.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 4803 entries, 19995 to 185567
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   title   4803 non-null   object
 1   sequel  90 non-null     Int64 
dtypes: Int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 117.3+ KB
```

My question is: is there a way to manipulate `my_sequels` to be similar to `sequels`, that is, to have `my_sequels['sequel']` as an object with 4803 non-null where `<NA>` becomes `nan`?

**EDIT**: the reason I wanted to have `my_sequels` to be the same as `sequels` was to avoid the errors from the subsequent steps:

```
sequels_fin = my_sequels.merge(financials, on='id', how='left')

orig_seq = sequels_fin.merge(sequels_fin, how='inner', left_on='sequel', 
                             right_on='id', right_index=True,
                             suffixes=('_org','_seq'))

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-7215de303684> in <module>
      3 orig_seq = sequels_fin.merge(sequels_fin, how='inner', left_on='sequel', 
      4                              right_on='id', right_index=True,
----> 5                              suffixes=('_org','_seq'))
ValueError: cannot convert to 'int64'-dtype NumPy array with missing values. Specify an appropriate 'na_value' for this dtype.
```

Comment: If you wanted to you could use `df['sequel'].astype(str)` but really that's like walking backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you would want to. The reason you are seeing this is the tutorial is based on an older version of Pandas than what you are using.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

You can detect and operate on missing values as you would probably expect.

```py
arr = pd.array([1, 2, None], dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
arr.isna()
array([False, False,  True])
arr.fillna(0)
<IntegerArray>
[1, 2, 0]
Length: 3, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 1):

First index 'id':

```
sequels_fin = sequels_fin.set_index('id')
```

After:

```
orig_seq = sequels_fin.merge(sequels_fin, how='inner', left_on='sequel', 
                             right_on='id', right_index=True,
                             suffixes=('_org','_seq'))
```